# How to $_POST input text related to checkbox array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, input, checkbox

I have checkboxes for days of week like below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="day[]" id="monday" value="Monday">
<label for="monday">Monday</label>
<input name="day-detail[]" type="text" />

<input type="checkbox" name="day[]" id="tuesday" value="Tuesday">
<label for="tuesday">Tuesday</label>
<input name="day-detail[]" type="text" />
```

And so on.

Notice that there is related input text for each day.

I would like to know if is possible for me to print the input text field only if the checkbox is checked. I need to do this several times with many others checkboxes so I tryed with the following function:

```
<?php
function checkboxes($checkbox_field, $default = '') {
    if(isset($_POST[$checkbox_field]) and !empty($_POST[$checkbox_field])) {
        $post_field = $_POST[$checkbox_field];
        if (is_array($post_field)) {
            if(!empty($_POST[$checkbox_field.'-detail'])) {
                return join(', ', $post_field.': '.$_POST[$checkbox_field.'-detail']);
                echo $_POST[$checkbox_field.'-detail'];
            }
            else {
                return join(', ', $post_field);
                echo $_POST[$checkbox_field.'-detail'];
            }
        }
    } else {
        return $default;
    }
}

echo "The weekly sales are:  ".checkboxes('day');
?>
```

This is what I'm trying to print:

> Monday: `value from text input`, Tuesday: `value from text input`"

The checked checkboxes are printed ok but the text inputs are not.

What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to use an index to the fields. So let's say Tuesday is selected. Then `$_POST["day"][1]` gives you `TRUE` (the checkbox), and `$_POST["day-detail"][1]` gives you the corresponding text (i.e. the 1 is used as an index to both fields).

In practice the index will actually be a variable in a `for` loop, as I'm imagining you looping over all checkboxes.

Comment: So the PHP structure that I posted won't work at all even with index to the fields? I shall try then `for` with `count` for the loop? Thanks!

Comment: To be honest I didn't understand the code you posted completely... it looks like you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. Having had a second glance, though, one thing that you're definitely doing wrong (in 2 places) is that you're doing a return and then an echo... the echo will never get called.